# Why wrap code into 'document ready'

Tags: jquery

I'm new to Jquery. See an example at http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_p. Here, clicking 'Click Me' button the text change. My question is why the following code need to wrapped under `$(document).ready(function(){ )}`. Otherwise, it doesn't work.

Thanks so much for all your help and really appreciate.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("p").hide();
  });
```

Comment: Because the DOM has to be fully loaded before you can `bind()` to an event. I'd suggest you read jQuery's [own documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) (`ready()` method described [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) instead of w3schools if you're serious about learning it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you didn't wrap this code in the `$(document).ready()` handler, the objects wouldn't exist because the DOM isn't loaded.

This is a simple test to ensure that the DOM is ready, before invoking methods on its elements.

Answer (score 3):

It makes sure all the DOM elements are loaded before trying to access them

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wrap it, it might not find your element. The page needs to be build first, and then you can look for certain elements to add some functions.

So you say "wait for the page to be finished loading, so all elements I want to change are there" before you start adding stuff to them.