# JQuery's multiDatesPicker not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need to implement a multi dates calendar. I tried to follow this example :
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Unfortunately this is not working, no error displayed on the console. Nothing happens. I probably forgot something.

Thanks in advance for your help. My code is as shown below.

**Included js files.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsCalendar/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsCalendar/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsCalendar/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsCalendar/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>
```

**Code inside the script tag to initialize the multiDatesPicker instance.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
        $("#date").multiDatesPicker();
        $("#btnRepercute").click(function () {
              $("#date").multiDatesPicker("show");
        });
</script>
```

**HTML to bind the multiDatesPicker instance.**

```
<input type="button" value="Répercuter" class="button" id="btnRepercute"/>
<input type="text" id="date" class="hidden" />
```

PS: i need the simplest usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to call the code when the document is ready.

Put your **Javascript** code in between those:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /* YOUR CODE HERE */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your code in `document ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   ------your code-----
});
```

see: [Why wrap code into 'document ready'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691454/why-wrap-code-into-document-ready)

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#date").multiDatesPicker();
    $("#btnRepercute").click(function () {
          $("#date").multiDatesPicker("show");
    });
});
```