# Form_Open always submits - Submitting Via Ajax - CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to submit my form via Ajax. I have done it before but for some reason whenever I click submit it will always submit the form and refresh the page. I made a test function just to console log once submit button is pressed but that doesn't even work.

Once I can get the console log working without page refreshing then I can do the Ajax myself since I know how.

Here is my form (keep in mind Im only going to post one input here just for an example).

```
function submit_form(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('working');
    return false;
};


   {!! form_open('myaccount/product_coupon/add',['id' => 'product_coupon_form', 'onsubmit'=> 'submit_form']) !!}

 Username <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control">

 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">

 </form>
```

I have also tried in javascript calling it by `$('#submit').click(function()...` but that still did nothing

Comment: Check if there is some JS error in console ?

Comment: If you want to submit your form using ajax then you don't need any form#action for that. You can do it on button click.

Comment: I tired leaving form action as "" and still nothing, keeps submitting. And there are no errors in the console log or success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st: be sure you include jquery

2nd: wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //code here })`

3rd: you can use *form submit* instead of *submit button click*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#product_coupon_form').on('submit' , function(e){
          submit_form(e);
     })
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you! Do you know why mine didn't work when I called it? why do I need to call document ready before it

Comment: @Gilbert read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6691454/why-wrap-code-into-document-ready and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894981/how-important-it-is-to-wrap-jquery-code-in-document-ready-function  .. summery of all of this .. is the * the objects wouldn't exist because the DOM isn't loaded.* but with `$(document).ready(function(){` its check for document is loaded first